# How to test slack api team_join event

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to automate a few things when we have a new user join our slack - is there a way to test the team_join api without creating multiple new users? I'm running out of email addresses to use

https://api.slack.com/events/team_join

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice thought! For now, I can suggest you to use disposable emails. You can have only one email say `christopher@gmail.com` and then you can use `christopher+mar25-2020@gmail.com`, `christopher+mar26-2020@gmail.com` and so on. Also, If I came to know about event testing will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Slack doesn't appear to currently have an API playground that allows you to send mock events. You can mock this out yourself by following these steps:

1. Send the event to yourself once using a real sign up
2. Save the incoming request payload in a fixture file for reference, e.g. `event-callback-team_join.json`
3. Send mock events with the same shape to your API in one of the following ways:

   1. Automation: using an automated process like unit tests or integration tests that leverage the fixture file (I take this approach in CI processes)
   2. Manually: Sending API requests to your API using the fixture data as the payload (I do this during development)

You've already implemented this, so I'm sure you already know the shape of the user object already, but just in case, you can see the [Slack user info model here](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info) and the `event_callback` [team_join event here](https://api.slack.com/events/team_join). Follow the links on those pages for additional metadata that's sent alongside each event callback.

Don't forget that Slack is also a web app not just a desktop app, so you can also write scripts with JavaScript to automate the invite flow, automatically creating emails with a specific pattern, and injecting them into the fields. You can do this with a script that's triggered manually (e.g. via a bookmarklet, copy/pasted into the console, or using a browser extension like [Form Filler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fake-filler/bnjjngeaknajbdcgpfkgnonkmififhfo?hl=en)), or via an end-to-end integration/UI test using a testing framework like [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/). This wouldn't be great for a real workspace as you may be tempted to put the username and password of the admin user in code, but there's ways around that.

Lots of options only limited by your creativity and comfort in each approach!

Answer (score 0):

1- Just create one email <`test-email@something.com`> and store/dump the incoming request data somewhere, probably some json file.

2- Use that data as request body to your application unlimited times with postman or any other request client :)